# "connectivity libraries needed are not found" error in IBM Data Studio

Tags: db2

**UPDATE**

I am getting the following error when I try to create a new database in IBM Data Studio v3.1.1.0.

```
The connectivity libraries that are needed for local or remote non-JDBC operations were not found. To provide these libraries, you can install IBM data server client or a local DB2 server instance.
```

I have already started the instance using

```
db2start
```

command.

After searching exhaustively, I am not able to find any help on the internet regarding this error.

Comment: Can you provide any SQL codes or reasons from the error? Also I am wondering where are you trying to create this on? Did you specify the node (local or remote)? to create the database on?

Comment: Do you have the DB2 server and Data Studio installed on the same machine? If not, you should follow the advice in the error message and install the DB2 client software. If yes, make sure that for the user that runs Data Studio the environment is set up correctly, so that the DB2 CLI libraries can be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to point IBM Data Studio to the database drivers. They are usually installed with DB2 under /myDB2_InstallationDirectory/SQLLIB/java.

The drivers themselves tend to be

- db2jcc.jar
- db2jcc_license_cu.jar

There are other drivers in that folder as well, but these two tend to be the main ones for Java (which IBM Data Studio is based on).